How to annotate type of an `OrderedDict` that is initialized with literals?
Suppose I have the following:
from collections import OrderedDict
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class HelloWorld:
    x: OrderedDict[str, int]


a = OrderedDict([("a", 0), ("c", 2), ("b", 1)])
HelloWorld(a) <--- # type error here

The type error produced is:
Argument of type "OrderedDict[Literal['a', 'c', 'b'], Literal[0, 2, 1]]" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "OrderedDict[str, int]" in function "__init__"
  "OrderedDict[Literal['a', 'c', 'b'], Literal[0, 2, 1]]" is incompatible with "OrderedDict[str, int]"
    Type parameter "_KT@OrderedDict" is invariant, but "Literal['a', 'c', 'b']" is not the same as "str"
    Type parameter "_VT@OrderedDict" is invariant, but "Literal[0, 2, 1]" is not the same as "int

Oddly enough, this very similar snippet does not produce an error:
from collections import OrderedDict
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class HelloWorld:
    x: OrderedDict[str, int]


HelloWorld(OrderedDict([("a", 0), ("c", 2), ("b", 1)])) # <--- no error


cast is often a viable solution, but here you can just annotate the initial variable. That will preserve the type safety of your code (unlike cast which can cast a str to dict[int, int] equally well). Pyright should have not complain about the following:
from collections import OrderedDict
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class HelloWorld:
    x: OrderedDict[str, int]

a: OrderedDict[str, int] = OrderedDict([("a", 0), ("c", 2), ("b", 1)])
HelloWorld(x=a)

And here's a playground.
This error is caused by overly optimistic inference of pyright together with OrderedDict invariance (as any MutableMapping).
As @InSync noticed in comments, on Python 3.7 and above you can build OrderedDict from a dict literal still preserving the order, and inference is less specific in that case:
a = OrderedDict({"a": 0, "c": 2, "b": 1})
HelloWorld(x=a)


In this specific case, it might be better to write OrderedDict({"a": 0, "c": 2, "b": 1}), which is inferred to be of type OrderedDict[str, int] without explicit annotation. A note about the overload Pyright chose would also be a good addition to this answer.

@InSync thanks! I incorporated the literal dict suggestion, but hardly understand what it has to do with the overload choice. Seems more like internal pyright inference detail - a literal dict inside the call expr is inferred as dict[str, int], while its tuple pairs are inferred as tuples of literals. Could you elaborate why you think specific overload resolution matters here?

The tuple elements are inferred to be of Literal types (e.g. ("a", 0) is inferred to be of type tuple[Literal["a"], Literal[0]]). The list thus matches the argument of dict(iterable: Iterable[tuple[_KT, _VT]]), with the element types merged (Literal["a", "b", "c"] as _KT and Literal[0, 1, 2] as _VT; you can hover over the OrderedDict call to confirm this). This is perhaps a by-design choice, because Pyright would otherwise consider [("a", 0), ("c", 2), ("b", 1)] to be of type list[tuple[str, int]].

Ah, well, pyright just doesn't infer literal-typed dict literals, neither in calls not standalone (reveal_type({'a': 1})), and here's why your suggestion works. I think it's clear enough that inference in the original snippet is based on tuple elements types, but feel free to edit that part into my answer or post as your own:)

@InSync but I cannot control order of insertion when using a dict as the input structure, right?

@bzm3r dict is ordered ever since 3.7 (3.6 if you use CPython), as noted in the answer. Really, OrderedDict is now just retained for historical reasons.

@InSync Oh yeah, I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6?noredirect=1&lq=1

So I might as well use dict, and not OrderedDict, and the ordering problems I was seeing were likely a result of my using set to contain  keys of interest? But maybe set is ordered too now, as a consequence of dict being ordered? Not sure. This raises a lot of questions, but of the good kind.

@bzm3r set is not ordered at all, you can easily see that (e.g. try {'a'*n for n in range(1,6)}). set in python is not implemented as a dict with empty values.

Use typing.cast:
from collections import OrderedDict
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import cast


@dataclass
class HelloWorld:
    x: OrderedDict[str, int]


a = OrderedDict([("a", 0), ("c", 2), ("b", 1)])
HelloWorld(cast(OrderedDict[str, int], a))

